Tailwind BreakPoints Not
I am build a simple div on that i want px-5 for mobile screen and px-20 for larger screen but only px-5 is working px-20 not working on large screen why?
Code Output Image
 <div class="bg-white py-20  px-5  lg:px-20 ">
        <div class="w-full md:w-1/2 mx-auto space-y-8">
          <div class="bg-white py-20 rounded-xl shadow-lg p-6 flex flex-col items-center justify-between">
            <div class="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-between w-full">
              <div class="flex py-4 flex-col md:flex-row justify-start w-full h-full">
                <div class="flex flex-col lg:ml-10  md:items-start">
                  <h2 class="text-xl md:text-4xl font-semibold mb-2 text-center md:text-left">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                  </h2>
                  <p class="text-gray-600 text-center md:text-left">
                    Porem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex flex-col justify-center sm:justify-center lg:justify-end md:flex-row mt-4 md:mt-0 w-full ">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Enter email here"
                  className="lg:w-96 sm:w-1/2 py-2 px-2 sm:px-10 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                  // Adjust the width here, sm:w-1/2 means the input width will be half of the container on small screens and above
                />
                <button
                  className="mt-3  lg:w-1/3 sm:mt-0 flex items-center justify-center md:ml-4 text-white py-3 px-4 rounded-sm hover:bg-orange-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-orange-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#F68219" }}
                  // Adjust the width here, sm:w-1/2 means the button width will be half of the container on small screens and above
                >
                  Start E-Filling Now
                  <img src="/arrow.svg" alt="" className="ml-2" />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

Expected Result Image
i want px-20 on large screen as shown in second image

If you want the margin on the left and right of the div, use margin instead padding.
 <div class="bg-white py-20 mx-5 lg:mx-20">


<div className="bg-white py-20  px-5  lg:px-20 ">
  <div className="w-full  mx-auto space-y-8">
    <div className="bg-white py-20 rounded-xl shadow-lg p-6 flex flex-col items-center justify-between lg:mx-20">
      <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center justify-between w-full">
        <div className="flex py-4 flex-col md:flex-row justify-start w-full h-full">
          <div className="flex flex-col lg:ml-10  md:items-start">
            <h2 className="text-xl md:text-4xl font-semibold mb-2 text-center md:text-left">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit
            </h2>
            <p className="text-gray-600 text-center md:text-left">
              Porem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-center sm:justify-center lg:justify-end md:flex-row mt-4 md:mt-0 w-full ">
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter email here"
            className="lg:w-96 sm:w-1/2 py-2 px-2 sm:px-10 border border-gray-300 rounded-sm focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
            // Adjust the width here, sm:w-1/2 means the input width will be half of the container on small screens and above
          />
          <button
            className="mt-3  lg:w-1/3 sm:mt-0 flex items-center justify-center md:ml-4 text-white py-3 px-4 rounded-sm hover:bg-orange-700 focus:outline-none focus:bg-orange-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out"
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#F68219" }}
            // Adjust the width here, sm:w-1/2 means the button width will be half of the container on small screens and above
          >
            Start E-Filling Now
            <img src="/arrow.svg" alt="" className="ml-2" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Check this out and compare. You were using the tailwind utilities in the wrong div. You can modify this piece of code to get what you expect.
